# What skills/perks are available in Skyrim?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Is there a list of skills/perks that are available to be selected in Skyrim?  This would allow you to plan your build without having to read them all in game.

Comment: And the Skyrim invasion begins!

Comment: I've removed obsolete comments from this thread, since the question has since been edited.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Final perk trees ( not just lists ) for 11 skills : http://forums.bethsoft.com/index.php?/topic/1250101-layout-of-perk-trees/

Answer (score 9):

Yes, there is a list available, coming from the beta: [Skyrim Perk List](http://theelderscrollsskyrim.com/racial-abilities-and-perk-trees/)
It's a list someone made after a beta test. For the full post, check out: [Full post](http://forums.bethsoft.com/index.php?/topic/1233644-sammus-eurogamer-qa/)